# How to skip C++ dll error in C# program

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c

It's my question that I've used a C++ DLL written by another developing group. Unfortunately, there are errors in functions (divide by 0, for example) that I call in my C# program. It causes my program to terminate suddenly.

Can anyone recommend how to fix it or skip this error, making sure that my program will not be  terminated any more ??

Comment: You can skip the error by not calling the function.  Fixing it requires recording a bug in the team's bug database.  Obvious answers, the magic you are looking for doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify that the dll is called through pinvoke or COM?

Did you get a DivideByZeroException?

If so, catch it, log it, and rethrow or throw a wrapper exception afterward.

You MUST NOT continue the business function/transaction, though the program might not necessarily be terminated.

I believe most modern development frameworks provide mechanisms to  catch uncaught exception, as the final safety net, though you may create one of your own.

Depend on the type of applications you are developing, for WinForm apps, you may check AppDomain.UnhandledException  or Application.ThreadException. For asp .net, depends on what framework you are using, there are many choices, for example, you may have a look at HttpApplication.Error .

Comment: This is the way I call Dll function [DllImport("Simple_Cpp_dll.dll", EntryPoint = "Test", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]

Comment: I intend to create a dll Simple_Cpp_dll with an error in function Test(). Then I call this function in a C# program. Program is terminated when running at the point of calling Test().

Comment: If you run Code Analysis and read the online help of those CA warnings, you will get some hints, along with the comments I made above, to fix the problem.

Comment: I would do this way [DllImport("Simple_Cpp_dll.dl", SetLastError = true, ...)], then                     int hr = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    if (hr != 0)
                    {
                        throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(hr); please also check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx
                    }